# How would I build a selfStart with custom formula or insert my formula into nls()?

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression, self-starting

Please bear with me, as this is my first post in my first month of starting with R. I have some biphasic decay data, an example of which is included below:

| N | Time | Signal |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.0001101 | 2.462455 |  |  |
| 2 | 0.0002230 | 2.362082 |  |  |
| 3 | 0.0003505 | 2.265309 |  |  |
| 4 | 0.0004946 | 2.180061 |  |  |
| 5 | 0.0006573 | 2.136348 |  |  |
| 6 | 0.0008411 | 2.071639 |  |  |
| 7 | 0.0010487 | 2.087519 |  |  |
| 8 | 0.0012832 | 1.971550 |  |  |
| 9 | 0.0015481 | 2.005190 |  |  |
| 10 | 0.0018473 | 1.969274 |  |  |
| 11 | 0.0021852 | 1.915299 |  |  |
| 12 | 0.0025669 | 1.893703 |  |  |
| 13 | 0.0029981 | 1.905901 |  |  |
| 14 | 0.0034851 | 1.839294 |  |  |
| 15 | 0.0040352 | 1.819827 |  |  |
| 16 | 0.0046565 | 1.756207 |  |  |
| 17 | 0.0053583 | 1.704472 |  |  |
| 18 | 0.0061510 | 1.630652 |  |  |
| 19 | 0.0070464 | 1.584315 |  |  |
| 20 | 0.0080578 | 1.574424 |  |  |
| 21 | 0.0092002 | 1.493813 |  |  |
| 22 | 0.0104905 | 1.349054 |  |  |
| 23 | 0.0119480 | 1.318979 |  |  |
| 24 | 0.0135942 | 1.242094 |  |  |
| 25 | 0.0154536 | 1.115491 |  |  |
| 26 | 0.0175539 | 1.065381 |  |  |
| 27 | 0.0199262 | 0.968143 |  |  |
| 28 | 0.0226057 | 0.846351 |  |  |
| 29 | 0.0256323 | 0.765699 |  |  |
| 30 | 0.0290509 | 0.736105 |  |  |
| 31 | 0.0329122 | 0.588751 |  |  |
| 32 | 0.0372736 | 0.539969 |  |  |
| 33 | 0.0421999 | 0.467340 |  |  |
| 34 | 0.0477642 | 0.389153 |  |  |
| 35 | 0.0540492 | 0.308323 |  |  |
| 36 | 0.0611482 | 0.250392 |  |  |
| 37 | 0.0691666 | 0.247006 |  |  |
| 38 | 0.0782235 | 0.177039 |  |  |
| 39 | 0.0884534 | 0.174750 |  |  |
| 40 | 0.1000082 | 0.191918 |  |  |

I have multiple curves to fit a double falling exponential that has the general formula where some fraction of the particle A is decaying fast (described by k1) and then the remaining fraction of particle A decays slowly (described by k2), summarized below:

where A is the particle fraction, k1 is a fast rate, k2 is the slow rate, and T is time. I believe should be entered as

`DFE <- y ~ (A*exp(-c*t)) + ((A-b)*exp(-d*t))`

I would like to create a selfStart code to apply to over 40 sets of data without having to guess the start values each time. I found some [R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/selfStart) for this, but can't figure out where to go from here.

The problem is that I am very new to R (and programming in general) and really don't know how to do this. I have had success (meaning convergence was achieved) with

```
nls(Signal~ SSasymp(Time, yf, y0, log_alpha), data = DecayData)
```

which is a close estimate but not a truly good model. I was hoping I could somehow alter the SSasymp code to work with my equation, but I think that I am perhaps too naive to know even where to begin.

I would like to compare the asymptotic model with my double falling exponential, but the double falling exponential model never seems to reach convergence despite many, many, many trials and permutations. At this point, I am not even sure if I have entered the formula correctly anymore. So, I am wondering how to write a selfStart that would ideally give me extractable coefficients/half-times.

Thanks so much!

Edit:
As per Chris's suggestion in the comments, I have tried to insert the formula itself into the nls() command like so:

```
DFEm = nls("Signal" ~ (A*exp(-c*Time)) + ((A-b)*exp(-d*Time)), data = "Signal", trace= TRUE)
```

which returns

> "Error in nls(Signal ~ (A * exp(-c * Time)) + ((A - b) * exp(-d * : 'data' must be a list or an environment"

So I am unsure of how to proceed, as I've checked spelling and capitalization. Is there something silly that I am missing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I will first qualify and say, I know nothing about your excellent formula, but you do and you already know Signal~SSasymp is a near enough estimate, and you discern that your formula is a better model for your investigation,  Looking at `nls` documentation, you should see you don't have to start with the 'start' formula lapproach of Signal ~ SSasymp, but put your formula, as per the docs. `nls(your formula, ` Welcome and plug away.

Comment: @Chris Hi and thanks! I have tried....."DFEm = nls("BGsubNorm" ~ (A*exp(-c*Time)) + ((A-b)*exp(-d*Time)), data = "BGsubNorm", trace= TRUE)".....which returns........"Error in nls(Signal ~ (A * exp(-c * Time)) + ((A - b) * exp(-d *  :  'data' must be a list or an environment"......and so I am unsure of how to proceed, as I've checked spelling and capitalization and also tried to add quotes around Signal and Time. Is there something silly that I am missing?

Comment: So, edit your post above to show what you tried, if it is different/beyond what you detailed already. I was just looking at [nls](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/nls), so now you have your OK estimate from SSasymp, perhaps put your formula in `nls(your-formula, start = SSasymp result` , but I'll confess I'm just guessing. Edit your title to put in nls and an expert might appear.

Comment: Reading carefully, you see that, for the moment, the formula part is not a problem, but that ` 'data' must be a list or an environment`, so `str(DecayData)` , is it a list?

Comment: Hello, I haven't exactly answered the question, but found a workaround with another program. I could not figure out how to build my own selfStart, so I ended up using Jmp to fit the double falling exponential, as they have the actual formula as a built-in model and allow feeding of the data and iterative fitting to get estimates of variables. From there, I just pulled out estimated values and used them as start values in R. 
With those values, the nls() functioned fine with my inputted formula, convergence reached and all. Thanks for all the help!